# Can someone help me figure out why one of my methods is not running at all?

Tags: java, infinite-loop

Why when I run my program and enter 5, it allows me to enter my records, but when the main menu runs again and I enter 6, the changePhoneNumber method is not run and it goes back to the main menu. Is the while(true) loop somehow messing things up?
 I have a class called Record that looks like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BankMethods method = new BankMethods();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int optionSelected = 0;

    while(true){

    System.out.println("5. Add a New Record");
    System.out.println("6. Change the Phone Number in the Current Record");

    optionSelected = input.nextInt();

if (optionSelected == 5){
        Scanner getRecord = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter First Name: ");
        String firstName = getRecord.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Last Name: ");
        String lastName = getRecord.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Phone Number: ");
        String phoneNumber = getRecord.nextLine();

        method.addNewRecord(firstName, lastName, phoneNumber);


    }
    if (optionSelected == 6){
        System.out.println("What would you like to change your phone "
                + "number to? ");
        String newNumber = input.nextLine();
        method.changePhoneNumber(newNumber);

    }
```

and the other class...BankMethods:

```
public class BankMethods {
LinkedList recordInformation = new LinkedList();
Bankdata mainMenu = new Bankdata();


public void addNewRecord(String firstName, String lastName, 
        String phoneNumber){
    recordInformation.add(firstName); recordInformation.add(lastName);
    recordInformation.add(phoneNumber);
}

public void changePhoneNumber(String newNumber){
    recordInformation.set(2, newNumber);
    System.out.println(recordInformation);
}
```

Comment: use proper formatting

Comment: what is not formatted correctly

Comment: Use `Alt`+`Shift`+`F` and you will see properly formated code. Right now your `BankMethods` class could use that.

Comment: main is not formatted correctly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is to use one read(scanner)  for a input stream.  Edited the previous answer to use single read option
Complete program that works is given below

```
package com.stackoverflow.framework;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Record {

    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static String readData() {
        return (input.nextLine());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BankMethods method = new BankMethods();

        int optionSelected = 0;

        while (true) {

            System.out.println("5. Add a New Record");
            System.out
                    .println("6. Change the Phone Number in the Current Record");

            optionSelected = Integer.parseInt(readData());

            if (optionSelected == 5) {
                // Scanner getRecord = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Enter First Name: ");
                String firstName = readData();
                System.out.println("Enter Last Name: ");
                String lastName = readData();
                System.out.println("Enter Phone Number: ");
                String phoneNumber = readData();
                method.addNewRecord(firstName, lastName, phoneNumber);

            }
            if (optionSelected == 6) {
                System.out.println("What would you like to change your phone "
                        + "number to? ");
                // Scanner getRecord = new Scanner(System.in);
                String newNumber = readData();
                method.changePhoneNumber(newNumber);

            }
        }
    }
}

class BankMethods {
    LinkedList recordInformation = new LinkedList();

    public void addNewRecord(String firstName, String lastName,
            String phoneNumber) {
        recordInformation.add(firstName);
        recordInformation.add(lastName);
        recordInformation.add(phoneNumber);
    }

    public void changePhoneNumber(String newNumber) {
        recordInformation.set(2, newNumber);
        System.out.println(recordInformation);
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe the problem is in using multiple Scanners for the same InputStream, as in the other answer.

Comment: @user2012751, second semester is just time to learn debugging by yourself.

Comment: @rdcrng  Thanks for your comment. I have updated the code accordingly

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are using 2 `Scanners` to read the one `InputStream`. When you open the second `Scanner` you will not be able to read using the original one as the second will have exclusive access to it.

For this application you could easily use a single `Scanner`.

See: [Do not create multiple buffered wrappers on a single InputStream](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/FIO06-J.+Do+not+create+multiple+buffered+wrappers+on+a+single+InputStream)